# Count paths in a matrix

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

This is a question from homework, that I got stuck with, and I'll be happy if someone could direct me.

A legal path is defined, by statring at the first cell (row 0 collumn 0), and countinue to the next step by adding the first and the second digits of the number in the cell, untill reaching the last cell (row n collumn n).

For example:
If in cell [2][3] there is the number 15, then the next move can be:
+1 in rows and +5 in collumns to [3][8]
or
+5 in row and +1 in collumns to [7][4]

The method should return how many legal paths are there.

I'm trying to use a backtracing recursive method for this problem, and I can't use any loops or any other method but overloading methods.

Here is the code I came up with so far:

```
public static int countPaths (int[][] mat)
{
    return countPaths(mat,0,0);
}

private static int countPaths(int[][] mat, int col, int row)
{


    if ((col==mat.length-1 && row==mat[0].length-1 )  {
        return 1;
    }    
    return countPaths(mat,mat[col][row]/10+col,mat[col][row]%10+row) + countPaths(mat,mat[col][row]%10-col,mat[col][row]/10-row);

}
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg the problem is that OP *got stuck* with this and needs help. It is a valid question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I just don't see where he is stuck. Would be a whole lot easier to answer the question if I knew more. Is there something that is not working as expected? What is the result of the code today? What is missing?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Read the problem statement. Then, read the code provided by OP. If you understand both, then you could note that the current design of the recursive method doesn't handle a backtracking solution (which is a tag in the question).

Comment: Not to be off topic, but this problem should not be solved using recursion in the first place.  You should tell your teacher to get a better example.

Comment: I totally would have used recursion. How would you solve it?

Comment: OP, Simon has a point; it would help if you explained the problem. (Although I already see it)

(Hint: when will countPaths() return 0?)

Comment: @ Itay4  - offtopic - You may  refactor code that extract digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, this is a solution.

public class MatrixPathCounter {
    private static int[][] mat = {{10,11,0},{10,11,10},{10,10,0}};

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(countPath(mat,0,0));
}

private static int countPath(int[][] mat, int x, int y)
{
    int n = mat.length -1;

    if (x==n && y==n)
        return 1;

    if(x>n || y>n)
        return 0;

    if(mat[x][y]==0)
        return 0;

    if(x+mat[x][y]/10 == x+mat[x][y]%10 && x+mat[x][y]%10 == x+mat[x][y]/10)
        return countPath(mat,x+mat[x][y]/10,y+mat[x][y]%10);
    else
        return countPath(mat,x+mat[x][y]/10,y+mat[x][y]%10) + countPath(mat,x+mat[x][y]%10,y+mat[x][y]/10 ); 
}
```

}

Comment: You're assuming a square matrix.

Comment: p.s. for homework assignments, you shouldn't be giving a completed answer; just hints. (Just my opinion, but I'm always right.)

Comment: @EdwardFalk  I assumed this because he said : ...untill reaching the last cell (row n collumn n)

Comment: Ahh, ok. Probably a reasonable assumption then.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a homework , so just some hints from me

1. Instead of only returning 1 also return a failure state. for example if the column or row is larger than the length then return 0. ( or you can use true/false)
2. you are adding two recursive function. instead of doing this try doing one by one. For example at first check using (row+1,com+5) if it retunrs failure then try (row+5,col+1).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. If i do the functions one by one, then how should i returns how many legal paths are there, I need to count the paths.

Comment: oh i missed that.. ok you can use a counter variable. it will increase 1 at each recursion .. if recursion returns true then the couter will be your path length . if false then decrease by 1. NOt a fullproof idea as I am not coding right now.. you can try thinking this

Answer (score 0):

```
    return countPaths(mat,mat[col][row]/10+col,mat[col][row]%10+row) + countPaths(mat,mat[col][row]%10-col,mat[col][row]/10-row);
```

"A legal path is defined, by statring at the first cell (row 0 collumn 0), and countinue to the next step by adding the first and the second digits of the number in the cell, untill reaching the last cell (row n collumn n).

For example: If in cell [2][3] there is the number 15, then the next move can be: +1 in rows and +5 in collumns to [3][8] or +5 in row and +1 in collumns to [7][4]"

It sounds to me like like your logic in determining row and col is off by some degree. You should be getting the same two digits regardless, just switching them around. My recommendation is to store your digit values inside of a variable to make your code more legible. I see how to solve the problem, but you won't learn anything if I solve it for you.

I would also, as another user has pointed out, make sure to close "dead end" paths by checking if they are still valid. At that point, return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, a few things:

- There seems to be an error in your calculation of the possible next steps to try
- You should check bounds before accessing the array / making the recursive call, to avoid ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] mat = 
        {
                {12, 22, 23, 54},
                {43, 35, 21, 20},
                {34, 21, 43, 21},
                {25, 30, 0,  20},
                {0,  22, 10, 10},
                {20, 13, 3,  45},
        };
    
    System.out.println(countPaths(mat)); // 3
}

public static int countPaths(int[][] mat)
{
    return countPaths(mat, 0, 0);
}

private static int countPaths(int[][] mat, int row, int col)
{           
    if (row == mat.length - 1 && col == mat[row].length - 1)
        return 1;
    
    if (row >= mat.length || col >= mat[row].length)
        return 0;
    
    if (mat[row][col] <= 0 || mat[row][col] >= 100)
        return 0;
    
    int currentNumber = mat[row][col];
    int rightDigit = currentNumber % 10, leftDigit = (currentNumber / 10) % 10;
    
    int r1 = countPaths(mat, row + rightDigit, col + leftDigit);
    int r2 = countPaths(mat, row + leftDigit, col + rightDigit);
    
    return r1 + r2;
}
```